# Unparseable date exception Creating a date from two objects

Tags: java, date, converters, milliseconds, jspinner

i'm using JXDatePicker and JSpinner to input date and time from the user.

I then need to format it back to one date in a long millisecond format.

with input of 03/09/2014 in JXDatePicker , the output from the JXDatePicker  is:

```
Wed Sep 03 00:00:00 IDT 2014
```

and with input of 11:00 in JSpinner, the output from JSpinner is :

```
Thu Jan 01 22:33:00 IST 1970
```

I need to combine both this outputs to get the full date , and then convert it to a long in millis.

I use this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("DDD MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String string_date = 
         datePicker.getDate().toString().substring(0, 11) +
         datePicker.getDate).toString().substring(24, 28) +
         hourPicker.getValue().toString().substring(10,19);
Date d;   
    try {
        d = f.parse(string_date);
    } catch (ParseException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and get this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Sep 17 2014 12:44:22"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at MainFrame.sendButtonActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:598)
    at MainFrame.access$3(MainFrame.java:574)
    at MainFrame$3.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:434)
```

please help !

thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse Wed use 'EEE' like show below, list of valid flags are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
class Test
 {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
         SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
         String string_date = "Wed Sep 17 2014 12:44:22";
         System.out.println(f.parse(string_date));

     }

  }
```